# How to force enable PAE at Windows Setup Startup

Tags: windows, setup, pae

Is there a way to force Windows Setup to enable PAE (physical adress extension) at start up, like I can do with linux installations ("/forcepae")?

I found an MSDN-Page about Physical Address Extension. Microsoft is telling to use

```
bcdedit /set [{ID}] pae ForceEnable
```

but I can't do this before windows setup is loading.

Comment: What exactly do you need to do in Windows Setup that requires PAE?

Comment: I would like to install Windows with PAE support on a [Intel Pentium M "Dothan/Banias"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_M) based machine, this processor supports PAE - but don't show PAE support flag.

Comment: Again I don't see why you need to do this in Windows setup. Setup does not need 4GB RAM.

Comment: Windows 8 won't install without PAE support, that's why I want to do so

Comment: Ah, sorry. I wasn't aware it checked for PAE support. There seem to be a lot of workarounds for installing it on Pentium M's but they all seem to refer to the preview release.

Comment: No problem. My idea is to run setup from custom WinPE, maybe I can change bcdedit there. But I've no idea how to execute Win 8 Setup this way.

Comment: Assuming your custom WinPE (is it on a USB?) uses the standard NT kernel (it probably does) then the same BCDEdit command *should* work just the same when applied to BCD store on the USB stick.